# Request.Url changed to always provide lower case url?

Tags: asp.net

I have an old site with many old sins in it's source and one of them is that i have an if statement checking the Request.Url string if it contains "Default.aspx". This has worked once upon the time but yesterday i realized that this doesn't work any more cause the URL returned is always in lower case (although my file name is Default.aspx).

Is this some strange little fix that has been done to IIS or to asp.net? I suppose it could have been something that i have done as well but i thought i might as well ask, maybe some of you know something about this, or if any global setting somewhere could cause this.

Comment: Not sure of a change. But IIS doesn't care about case, so it will accept default.aspx, Default.aspx, DEfaULt.aspx. Request.Url will return whatever was requested, not the actual file name that is run. Did you change a link to the page or something, or do you mean the root / is now requesting it as default.aspx and used to as Default.aspx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your if statement could be like this:

```
if(Request.Url.ToLower().Contains("default.aspx"))
{
    //to do...
}
```

Comment: Regardless of if there is some type of global setting (which I *hope* doesn't exist), this is by far the absolute best way to approach testing if one string is equal to another.

Answer (score 0):

Urls are case-sensitive, but ASP.NET is not.  You will have to `.ToLower()` your strings for comparison.

Also, check to see what your `default document` in IIS is set as, maybe it got changed to `default.aspx`.

[Setting Up Default Documents (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true)

[Configuring Default Documents in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753615%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you could make an httpmodule to permanently redirect (301) any urls that have have upper-cased chars to its lower-cased equivalent; you wouldn't have to change any of your equality checks that way...